# ¿Como puedo calcular los números impares de un array usando 2 métodos diferentes?

Tags: java

Tengo que crear un programa que pida al usuario 20 números y después ver cuáles de esos números son impares e imprimirlos.

Este es mi código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {

   public static int[] nums;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int cal1=0;
      Scanner calificaciones = new Scanner (System.in);
      nums = new int [20];

        //aqui se insertan los valores del arreglo
      System.out.println("ingrese 20 numeros:");
      for (int i = 0;i < 20; i++){
         cal1=calificaciones.nextInt();
         nums [i]=cal1;
      }
   }

   public static void esImpar () {
      for(int i = 0; i < 20;i++) {
         if (nums[i]%2==1) {
            System.out.println(nums[i]);
         }
      } 
   }
}
```

A la hora de correr el programa, lo que hace es que permite ingresar los 20 números, pero ya después no ejecuta el segundo método para calcular los impares.

Comment: Eso no es Javascript, es Java xd

Comment: Hola Angel, solo necesitas agregar ***esImpar ();*** después del for del main, ya que no estabas llamando a la función desde ningún lugar. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla! 
Cuando respondas al comentario de alguien, escribe "@nombreDelQueComento", para que este sea notificado.

Comment: Para saber si es par debe ser:  if (nums[i]%2==0)

Answer (score 2):

Solo tendrías que llamar a la función `esImpar`. Para eso escribe su nombre seguido de paréntesis:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int cal1 = 0;
    Scanner calificaciones = new Scanner(System.in);
    nums = new int[20];

    // ...

    esImpar();
}
```

---

Por cierto, dale nombres más descriptivos a tus variables y funciones.

Piensa en lo que te viene a la mente con solo leer su nombre si no tuvieras ni idea de qué hace o para qué sirve.

Por ejemplo, `esImpar` sugiere que recibe **un solo número** como parámetro y **devuelve verdadero o falso**. `imprimirImpares` suena mejor.

Answer (score 2):

Al terminar de obtener los números envía el array a tu método `esImpar()`, modifícalo para que reciba el array, es importante saber que esta operación es la que determina si es par un valor: `numero % 2 == 0`, por lo tanto tu método quedaría así:

```
   public static void esImpar(int[] nums) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if (nums[i] % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Es par: " + nums[i]);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Es impar: " + nums[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Este sería el código llamando el nuevo método:

```
  public static int[] nums;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        int cal1 = 0;
        Scanner calificaciones = new Scanner(System.in);
        nums = new int[20];

        //aqui se insertan los valores del arreglo
        System.out.println("ingrese 20 numeros:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            cal1 = calificaciones.nextInt();
            nums[i] = cal1;
        }
        
        //*Llama método para imprimir que números son par o impar.
        esImpar(nums);
        
    }
    
   //public static void esImpar() {
    public static void esImpar(int[] nums) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if (nums[i] % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Es par: " + nums[i]);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Es impar: " + nums[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Debido a que la respuesta de Mateo, soluciona el problema, esta debería tomarse como un  anexo, cuyo único mérito es hacer las funciones reutilizables (mediante el paso de parámetros) y evitar el "crasheo" del programa ante entradas incorrectas.
Seguimos su recomendación de dar nombres descriptivos a las variables.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    public void obtenerNumeros( int cantidad ) {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
       int numeros[] = new int[ cantidad ];
         //aqui se insertan los valores del arreglo
       System.out.println( "ingrese " + cantidad + " números:" );
       boolean incompleto = true;
       int i = 0;
       while( incompleto ) {
          try {  
             // evitamos que entradas erróneas crasheen el programa
             numeros[ i ] = scan.nextInt();
             i++;
             if( i == cantidad ) {
                incompleto = false;
             }
             else {
                System.out.println( "ingrese otro número" );
             }
          }
          catch( Exception e ) { 
             scan.nextLine();
             System.out.println( "ingrese un número válido" );
          }             
       }
       imprimeImpares( numeros );
    }    
    
    public void imprimeImpares( int listaNumeros[] ) {
       for( int i = 0; i < listaNumeros.length; i++ ) {
          if( listaNumeros[ i ] % 2 == 1 ) {  // se puede usar % 2 != 0
             System.out.println( listaNumeros[ i ] );
          }
       } 
    }
    
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
         // creamos un objeto de la clase
       Main objetoDeLaClase = new Main();          
        // usando este objeto, evitamos crear métodos estáticos.
       objetoDeLaClase.obtenerNumeros( 3 );  // nombre sugerencia de Mateo.
    }
}
```